Develop unit reading WKB binary from SQL Server
I want to  convert a Well known binary string WKB into a geometrical  object in Delphi.  I read the content from an SQL Server database with this command
geomString := FieldbyName('Geom').AsString;

As a next step I must convert  this  information into a polygon. All my data are just simple polygons. I have written this small unit, I did not find any starting point somewhere else.
interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Math, System.Types;

type
  WKBByteOrder = (wkbXDR, // Big Endian
    wkbNDR // Little Endian
    );

  /// <summary>
  /// Well-known text (WKT) is a text markup language for representing vector
  /// geometry objects. A binary equivalent, known as well-known binary (WKB)
  /// </summary>
  /// <remarks>
  /// <para>
  /// see also:
  /// </para>
  /// <para>
  /// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#Well-known_binary
  /// https://libgeos.org/specifications/wkb/
  /// </para>
  /// </remarks>
  WKBGeometryType = (wkbPoint = 1, wkbLineString = 2, wkbPolygon = 3,
    wkbTriangle = 17, wkbMultiPoint = 4, wkbMultiLineString = 5,
    wkbMultiPolygon = 6, wkbGeometryCollection = 7, wkbPolyhedralSurface = 15,
    wkbTIN = 16, wkbPointZ = 1001, wkbLineStringZ = 1002, wkbPolygonZ = 1003,
    wkbTriangleZ = 1017, wkbMultiPointZ = 1004, wkbMultiLineStringZ = 1005,
    wkbMultiPolygonZ = 1006, wkbGeometryCollectionZ = 1007,
    wkbPolyhedralSurfaceZ = 1015, wkbTINZ = 1016, wkbPointM = 2001,
    wkbLineStringM = 2002, wkbPolygonM = 2003, wkbTriangleM = 2017,
    wkbMultiPointM = 2004, wkbMultiLineStringM = 2005, wkbMultiPolygonM = 2006,
    wkbGeometryCollectionM = 2007, wkbPolyhedralSurfaceM = 2015, wkbTINM = 2016,
    wkbPointZM = 3001, wkbLineStringZM = 3002, wkbPolygonZM = 3003,
    wkbTriangleZM = 3017, wkbMultiPointZM = 3004, wkbMultiLineStringZM = 3005,
    wkbMultiPolygonZM = 3006, wkbGeometryCollectionZM = 3007,
    wkbPolyhedralSurfaceZM = 3015, wkbTinZM = 3016);

type
  TWKBReadError = class(Exception);

type
  TPolygon = TArray<TPointF>;

function WellknownBinary2Geom(const s: string): TPolygon;

implementation

procedure ReverseBytes(var Bytes: TBytes);
var
  i: Integer;
  Temp: Byte;
begin
  for i := 0 to (Length(Bytes) div 2) - 1 do
  begin
    Temp := Bytes[i];
    Bytes[i] := Bytes[Length(Bytes) - 1 - i];
    Bytes[Length(Bytes) - 1 - i] := Temp;
  end;
end;

function ReadDouble(var Buffer: TBytes; var Offset: Integer;
  IsBigEndian: Boolean): Double;
var
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  if Offset + SizeOf(Double) > Length(Buffer) then
    raise TWKBReadError.Create('Buffer overflow while reading double');
  SetLength(Bytes, SizeOf(Double));
  Move(Buffer[Offset], Bytes[0], SizeOf(Double));
  Inc(Offset, SizeOf(Double));

  if IsBigEndian then
    ReverseBytes(Bytes);

  Move(Bytes[0], Result, SizeOf(Double));
end;

function ReadUInt32(var Buffer: TBytes; var Offset: Integer;
  IsBigEndian: Boolean): UInt32;
var
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  if Offset + SizeOf(UInt32) > Length(Buffer) then
    raise TWKBReadError.Create('Buffer overflow while reading UInt32');
  SetLength(Bytes, SizeOf(UInt32));
  Move(Buffer[Offset], Bytes[0], SizeOf(UInt32));
  Inc(Offset, SizeOf(UInt32));

  if IsBigEndian then
    ReverseBytes(Bytes);

  Move(Bytes[0], Result, SizeOf(UInt32));
end;

function WellknownBinary2Geom(const s: string): TPolygon;
var
  Buffer: TBytes;
  Offset: Integer;
  ByteOrder: Byte;
  WKBType: UInt32;
  NumRings: UInt32;
  NumPoints: UInt32;
  Points: TPolygon;
  IsBigEndian: Boolean;
begin
  // Convert input string to byte array
  Buffer := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
  Offset := 0;

  // Read byte order
  ByteOrder := Buffer[Offset];
  Inc(Offset);

  IsBigEndian := ByteOrder = 0;

  // Read WKB type
  WKBType := ReadUInt32(Buffer, Offset, IsBigEndian);

  if WKBType <> Ord(wkbPolygon) then
    raise TWKBReadError.Create('Unsupported WKB type');

  // Read number of rings
  NumRings := ReadUInt32(Buffer, Offset, IsBigEndian);

  if NumRings <> 1 then
    raise TWKBReadError.Create('Unsupported number of rings');

  // Read number of points in the exterior ring
  NumPoints := ReadUInt32(Buffer, Offset, IsBigEndian);

  SetLength(Points, NumPoints);

  // Read points
  for var i := 0 to NumPoints - 1 do
  begin
    Points[i].X := ReadDouble(Buffer, Offset, IsBigEndian);
    Points[i].Y := ReadDouble(Buffer, Offset, IsBigEndian);
  end;

  Result := Points;
end;

end.

Debugging my data I already fail getting the expected WKBGeometryType  and pretty useless values for NumRings, NumPoints which makes it pretty  hard to continue.
The data on the SQL Server are correct, I can verify with this function in Delphi:
function SpatialIntegrityAsText(FServername, FDatabasename, FTableName,
  FFieldName: string; ID: Integer): String;
var
  FQuery: TQuery;
  FConnection: TTConnection;
  SQLSTR: string;

begin
  FConnection := TConnection.create(nil);
  FQuery := TQuery.create(nil);
  try
    FConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
    FQuery.Connection := FConnection;

    DBConnect(FServername, FDatabasename, FConnection);

    SQLSTR := 'SELECT ' + FFieldName + '.STAsText() FROM ' + FTableName +
      ' where REcordIndex=' + IntToStr(ID);

    // SQLSTR := 'SELECT ' + FFieldName + '.ToString() FROM ' + FTableName +
    // ' where REcordIndex=' + IntToStr(ID);

    FQuery.SQL.add(SQLSTR);

    FQuery.Open;

    Result := FQuery.Fields[0].asString + '<END>';

  finally
    FQuery.Free;
    FConnection.Free;
  end;

end;


I dunno delphi, but why not use the WKT string which is standard? geometryColumn.ToString() returns it even

Why reinvent the wheel? There are already Delphi libraries that can transform between WKB and WKT representations.

pls share the link  "Delphi libraries that can transform between WKB and WKT"

WKB in sql server is actually a CLR format, so you can probably just steal, i mean port, the code from https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/Geometry.java
